# Compatibility of ios5 and ios6

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6

I have a problem regarding incompatibility of ios5 vs ios6

While I was working on my project with ios5

```
label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
```

then updated to ios6

```
label.textAlignment = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
```

Once I run my code on the device which ios5 installed, that give me error.

I am about to upload my app to appstore, however I want my app also supports ios5 as well. How I am going to handle both ios5 and ios6!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [acceptable values for NSTextAlignment are](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSTextAlignment):

- NSTextAlignmentLeft
- NSTextAlignmentCenter
- NSTextAlignmentRight
- NSTextAlignmentJustified
- NSTextAlignmentNatural

Of those any of the first three will work equally under iOS 5 and 6.

`NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail` isn't really a valid type of text alignment though it'll look like `NSTextAlignmentNatural` at runtime because of the way the C enums line up.

So you'll need either to switch to `NSTextAlignmentLeft` across the board or to do a functionality check. Thankfully the change in text alignment type is in support of the new ability to push attributed strings to `UILabel` (and elsewhere) so that gives you something to hang off.

E.g.

```
if([label respondsToSelector:@selector(attributedText)])
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentNatural;
else
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
```

Though the else is technically redundant because `NSTextAlignmentLeft` is the default value.